# Alternating sums of numbers divisible by $7$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6$ be given integers, not divisible by $7$. Prove that at least one of the expressions of the form  $$\pm x_1\pm x_2\pm x_3\pm x_4\pm x_5\pm x_6$$ is divisible by $7$, where the signs are selected in all possible ways. (Generalize the statement to every prime number greater than two!)

Each term is in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ modulo $7$, but how do I use this to prove the result?

Comment: Are you assuming that the $x_i$ span the non-zero residues?  If so, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815816/prove-the-congruence-sum-r-1p-1rp-r-equiv-0-pmod-p/1815831?noredirect=1#comment3710149_1815831)

Comment: Of course, for that case you could just  pair each element with its additive inverse...so I suppose the problem is only interesting if the $x_i$ don't span the residues.

Comment: use $\{-3,-2,-1,1,2,3\}$ as your set of residues instead of 1-6. Also, note that the same sums can be obtained from $|x_1|,...,|x_6|$ as can be obtained from $x_1, ..., x_6$, so you only need to consider terms in $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair how does this make it out for arbitrary bigger primes ?

Comment: @Agawa001 Every odd prime is of the form $2k+1$, so you can use the set $\{1,2,3,\cdots,k\}$ since every further integer is equivalent mod $2k+1$ to one of these up to sign. (If $p=2$, then the statement is false.)

Comment: Follows very easily from Cauchy-Davenport: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-DavenportTheorem.html

Comment: @ErickWong: Maybe consider making your comment an answer, so that it can be accepted and this question can exit the queue?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan Sure, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see a direct pigeonhole argument, but it is very easy to prove this using [Cauchy-Davenport](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-DavenportTheorem.html) (which itself is fairly elementary).

We make the simple observation that an alternating sum $\pm x_1 \pm \cdots \pm x_6$ is $0$ iff *twice* the sum of the *positive* terms is equal to $x_1 + \cdots + x_6$.  This principle also works modulo $7$, so the claim holds if we know that some subset of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_6\}$ sums to a number congruent to $2^{-1}(x_1+\cdots+x_6)$ mod $7$.  Cauchy-Davenport assures us that in fact every possible residue is covered.

This generalizes completely to any prime except for $2$ (since we use the fact that $2$ has a multiplicative inverse).  For $p=2$ we only have one term (and the $\pm$ signs have no effect) so it the analogous claim is false.